# Why can I get Environment Variable that isn't defined in the Control Panel

Tags: java, windows

I'm using Java to get "USERDOMAIN" by

```
        String domainname = System.getenv("USERDOMAIN");
        System.out.println(domainname);
```

I can get the domain I want. However, I'm a little confused cause I can't find the "USERDOMAIN" under "**System Properties --> Advanced --> Environment Variables**". If it's not defined here, where is it defined? How can I know what Environment Variables I can get besides that listed on the Control Panel.

I have tested it on both win7 and win8. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The variables that aren't persisted in the registry get created dynamically. You'll see fixed system variables initially defined in the session's winlogon.exe process: `SystemDrive`, `SystemRoot`, `ProgramFiles`, `ProgramFiles(x86)`, `ProgramW6432`, `CommonProgramFiles`, `CommonProgramFiles(x86)`, `CommonProgramW6432`, `ProgramData`, `ALLUSERSPROFILE`, `PUBLIC`. Others get added or reloaded when a user logs on or when Explorer reloads its environment: `COMPUTERNAME`, `SESSIONNAME`, `LOGONSERVER`, `USERNAME`, `USERDOMAIN`, `USERPROFILE`, `APPDATA`, `LOCALAPPDATA`, `HOMEDRIVE`, `HOMEPATH`.

Comment: @eryksun That's a good addition with more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the command line, type [`set`](https://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm). Per the link, *Type SET without parameters to display the current environment variables.*

Comment: Thanks, it's fair enough